# Securing MBeans operations

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jmx, mbeans

I've got some MBean operations that I need to secure. I would like the users to be required to log in as the server admin and I would like this to be setup programmaticly or, preferably by a config file in the WAR, when the app is deployed. I want to avoid requiring the admin to set this up as a deployment step.

We're running glassfish, but platform neutral is preferred. However, glassfish specific config files would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Sun JDK allows you to perform access control by putting credentials in the filesystem, which would live outside your jar. See [the management guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#PasswordAccessFiles) for details.

However, since you want to control things from within your app, you can use JAAS to replace the file-based configuration with your own. See the java docs on [com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-com.sun/jmx/com/sun/jmx/remote/security/JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java.htm) for details.

You could programmatically inject your own JAAS provider, and then manage the authentication details however you like.